# Inherit from a parent URL mapping

Tags: prettyfaces

I am trying to inherit a mapping, according to the PrettyFaces reference guide it should work like this:
http://ocpsoft.com/docs/prettyfaces/snapshot/en-US/html_single/#config.mapping.parents

I tried with the 3.3.2 version and later with 3.3.2-SNAPSHOT but without success.
Everything works fine without inheritance but I do not like the duplication.

Here is some of my code:

```
  <url-mapping id="management">
    <pattern value="/management/" />
    <view-id value="/management.face" />
  </url-mapping>

  <url-mapping parentId="management" id="managementUsers">
    <pattern value="/users/" />
    <view-id value="/management-users.face" />
  </url-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few choices. Two of which are:

1. Without a leading slash on the child mapping

   <url-mapping id="management">
        <pattern value="/management/" />
        <view-id value="/management.face" />
     </url-mapping>

   <url-mapping parentId="management" id="managementUsers">
        <pattern value="users/" />
        <view-id value="/management-users.face" />
     </url-mapping>
2. Without a slash on the tail of the parent mapping

   <url-mapping id="management">
        <pattern value="/management" />
        <view-id value="/management.face" />
     </url-mapping>

   <url-mapping parentId="management" id="managementUsers">
        <pattern value="/users/" />
        <view-id value="/management-users.face" />
     </url-mapping>

I hope this helps.

~Lincoln

Comment: Thank you, it works.Please update the documentation, the store/category example which I took as a reference is not correct.

Comment: Should be accepted now, it was my first question... good work on the PrettyFaces and support by the way.

Comment: Hehe. Thank you. I was mostly giving you a hard time/play on words for the way you said, "Please update the documentation" :)